# passing of strings in C function

Tags: c, c-strings

i have the following problems in C programming.

I have an array of strings stored as words[10][50]. I want to extract each of the string from the array and then pass it on to another function. I tried on the following:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int Check_Anagram(char*,char*);

void main()
{
    char words[10][20];
    int i;
    int flag;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s\n",words[i][20]);
    }
    for(i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        flag = Check_Anagram(words[i][20],words[i-1][20]);      
    }
    getch();
}

int Check_Anagram(char *a,char *b)
{
    printf("%s %s\n",a,b);
    return 1;
}
```

This creates an exception during compiling.
Now i think that when i use the "printf" statement then this nomenclature works fine i.i words[i] prints the string "i" from the double dimension words array. When i try to do the same thing with the check function then the error occurs.

Can soemone point me how to do this passing ?

P.S. Please ignore any error in efficiency of program and likewise. I need your help and this is just a test program at learning string passing to a function
Thanks

Comment: How about posting all of the code? Without seeing how `words` is initialized, assuming it *is* initialized, there's not much that can be said.

Comment: Error 2 error C2664: 'Check_Anagram' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'char *' c:\users\sg0214275\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\anagram\anagram\anagram.cpp 22 1 anagram
Also there is some memory referencing error involving some hexadecimal addresses 
ill post the code here too

Comment: Could you provide the code of `check()` function? And neat formatting is always appreciated.

Comment: I'm already coughing my lungs up, get that `void main()` out of here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing `words[i][20]`. You need to pass `words[i]` instead **in both loops**. Try this:

```
for(i = 1; i < 3; i++) /* i < 3 */
{
    flag = Check_Anagram(words[i], words[i-1]);
}
```

Another problem is that you're reading `3` strings and trying to print `10`. So when you pass `words[3]` it contains garbage: `printf` tries to print garbage which need not be 0-terminated.

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x5c4fea5f (msvcr100d.dll) in anagram.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xffffffcc.

i get this error on doing that. I had tried it earlier too...didnt work

Answer (score 2):

In the first for loop, when i is 0, you're pointing to words[-1], that's your exception.

Answer (score 1):

> flag = Check_Anagram(words[i][20],words[i-1][20]);

You are passing the 21st letter of each word the Check_Anagram. Instead you should pass the words themselves:

```
flag = Check_Anagram(words[i],words[i-1]);
```

You have a similar problem where you use `scanf`. To read a line from the console to each word you would use:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    scanf("%s\n",words[i]);
}
```

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x5c4fea5f (msvcr100d.dll) in anagram.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xffffffcc.

i get this error on doing that. I had tried it earlier too...didnt work

Comment: yeah i did.i got the solution. thanks for all of your helps.
will post the correct code as soon as i am allowed to

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int Check_Anagram(char [],char []);

void main()
{
    char words[10][20];
    int i;
    int flag;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s\n",words[i]);
    }
    for(i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        flag = Check_Anagram(words[i],words[i-1]);      
    }
    getch();
}

int Check_Anagram(char a[],char b[])
{
    printf("%s %s\n",a,b);
    return 1;
}
```

I finally got it corrected thanks to the help of all users.
I have posted the corrected code for people who are struggling with passing of string extracted from an array of strings to another function. hope it helps.